# Advise me on my iPad app

Tags: ipad, ios4

I want to create an iPad app which holds 8 PDF files (each 5.0 MB) and 100 jpg images.

Is it ok to have a app with this much of content added into the resources?

Looking for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple limits the size of an app to 2GB (see [iTunes Connect Developers Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)). In order to be distributable over the cell network, it must be under 20MB, I think.